Установка React на VPS
Я сделал своё react приложение и при установке его на мой VPS сервер столкнулся с тем что у меня по просто не хватает оперативной памяти, по началу я получал след ошибку - FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
почитав статьи посоветовали сделать вот так NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" npm start, судя по тому что я ноде выделяю 4 гига, но на моём VPS всего 768 мб и мне этого всегда хватало, почему react на столько сильно жрёт оперативу, ошибка после выше упомянутой настройке пропала, но теперь вечный starting the development server
Как это решить?

Запускать development server на проде — идея крайне хреновая сама по себе

не понял, а где запускать

Вам надо сбилдить приложение и разместить его на вашем vps хостинге(html,js,css - положить в рутовые директории вэб сервера)

Так всё, я проект сбилдил и вправду всё получилось но теперь вторая проблема образовалась не знаю как её решить, у меня есть backend на express и он работает на порту 5000 а сам сайт на react работает на 3000 порту и когда я захожу на сайт, пытаюсь делать какие-то запросы к API получаю ошибку, это и логично что localhost:5000 он не находит, вот вопрос встал как мне связать теперь API на express и сам react что бы при запросах всё работало корректно
